# How can I bridge a USB "gap"?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb

*First off, I'm sorry if this question is not appropriate for this site - I am a regular user of other SE sites but this is my first foray on here. I've looked at some meta questions and this site seems the most appropriate for the nature of my question.*

I am thinking of buying a home weather station. The station I have in mind has a USB port. By design I can wire this up (to a Windows-based computer), some software runs on the computer, and ultimately I can publish weather data onto the internet.

This is great - exactly what I'm looking for - except for a small thing.

- I want to hang the weather station in my hallway, where we can
  readily see its readout. This will not be a problem as regards the
  station's sensors as they are designed to communicate wirelessly with
  the main unit.
- I want to be able to upload weather data to the web 24/7
- In the house itself, I have a bunch of PCs but they're all
  desktops/laptops, none of them run 24/7, furthermore none of them are
  in/near the hallway

However...

- In my garage, I do have a server which does run 24/7. This is a
  Windows 2003 domain controller that I set up several years ago. But
  it has a USB port, and will be easily meaty enough to run a piece of weather station upload software.
- I would like to use this underused server to connect to the weather
  station and upload data to the web. The problem is that the distance
  between the server, and where I would like to site the weather
  station, is probably about 10m. Also, there are two walls between the
  two.

So ideally I am looking for some wireless hookup between the two, which functionally would behave exactly as a USB cable would. Does anyone have any ideas how I might achieve this?

*Just a little further information: the internet router also sits in the garage, and the servers connect to it through a switch and wired network. Off this switch I run wired connections to a couple of wifi access points which sit in the loft of the house. So every device in the house itself is wifi'd rather than wired. Unfortunately I don't think running a cable from garage to loft to hallway would be feasible as it would be quite a long stretch.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices. There are [USB-to-twisted-pair](http://www.crestron.com/resources/product_and_programming_resources/catalogs_and_brochures/online_catalog/default.asp?jump=1&model=USB-EXT) hookups that promise ranges up to 300 feet (you have to deploy a wire along the way), or use up to 150ft of [network cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BDMK3S). There also are "[bridges](http://www.globaledgesoft.com/usb-over-wi-fi/)" that transport USB signaling over WiFi.

I've also heard of [USB-over-Ethernet](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb) bridges (also on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002C6J9ZW)).

Comment: Many thanks, there's some good information under those links